# Please help with the meaning of seal calligraphy writing on the following clay board

Tags: translation, seal, calligraphy

[image]

Please help with the meaning of seal calligraphy writing on the following clay board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a slightly different transcription, and a rough translation:

> #### 賞賜
>
> #### Bestowal
>
> ---
>
> 茲甲（申）（殿）恩澤四方⿰辵告（造）
>
> 福百ｘ*修（之）卽請特
>
> 賜甲ｘ窑⿹⿰二⿱气人瓦（瓷）器甁
>
> 盌（碗）琖（香）鑪（爐）尊洗等三百
>
> 六十九件供甲亯（享）
>
> 用㠯（以 > 已）
>
> <sub>*As @水巷孑蠻 pointed out, this is probably 「姓」.</sub>
>
> The *Jiǎshēn* Palace graces our lands, bringing happiness and fortune to the people; its embellishment, prompted by a call to Royal Favours, gifting the palace with (...), kilned ceramic vessels, bowls, wine cups, incense burners, and wash basins, amounting to 369 items. These are provided to the Palace for the enjoyment [of its residents].
>
> ---
>
> 示皇恩浩蕩
>
> *Notice of the vast generosity of Imperial Favours*
>
> ---
>
> #### 甲
>
> #### *Jiǎshēn* Palace

*Jiǎshēn* Palace is presumably the name of the palace of the mother of [Emperor Gāozōng of Sòng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Gaozong_of_Song). The palace gained this name, reflecting the day of [Jiǎshēn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%94%B2%E7%94%B3), when Gāozōng held a birthday ceremony for his mother. See e.g. [瓷器有「甲申殿」落款嗎？它又是什麼意思？又代表著什麼？ - 壹讀](http://read01.com/kEPPeE5.html).

Note: I cannot find the text that you've presented anywhere - this is probably a complete fake.

Comment: do you think that it’s a counterfeit / forgery, pretending to be an antique?

Comment: I thought it was a fake, a little reference about 甲申 殿
and some weird idiomatic sentences
thank you

Comment: dear dROOOze,
thank you for the input answers, for my learning.
regards,

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I don't even know what it's supposed to be a forgery of...the text is incomplete. Maybe it's targeted towards people who can't read seal characters.

Comment: imo, the text is unacceptable, pretending a “notice / record” in literary chinese. secondly, using clay / stone board for records is, un-chinese. 

Comment: @CDrihardjanto maybe this will help a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

the top two characters are: “賞賜” (read from right to left), which means rewarded

reading from the right, top to bottom, my initial reading is:

茲甲申殿恩澤四方造

福百姓修之ｘｘｘｘ

賜甲申殿ｘｘ瓷器瓶

ｘ琖香爐尊洗等三百

六十九件ｘ甲申殿合

用以

示皇恩浩蕩

the last three characters are:

“甲申殿”

a funny clay board :)

Comment: Dear my friend,
Thank you for a lovely time
you are the first to comment on a good answer
regards